# Order of 10 in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, totient-function

If I know the smallest positive $n$ such that $10^n \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ for $p$ prime, then
am I able to find the smallest positive $n'$ such that $10^{n'} \equiv 1 \pmod{p^2}$ and so on. I believe so, and it goes as follows.

$n' = pn \\
n'' = p^2 n \\ \vdots \\ n^{(k)} = p^k n$

I've tested it for a few $p$ and it seems to work, but I can't get a proof of it together. Any help would be greatly appeciated!

Comment: Note that for $p = 3$, then $10^{1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$, but we also have $10^{1} \equiv 1 \pmod{3^2}$, so $n' = n$ in that case.

Comment: For 3, the pattern seems to hold after $k = 2$, as $10^1 \equiv 1 \pmod{3^2} \\ 10^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{3^3} \\ 10^9 \equiv 1 \pmod{3^4}$ and so on.

I suspect it may just be a special case as $3^2 < 10$, since any other primes excluding 2 and 5 seem to follow the rule in the post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursive relation of multiplicative orders for integers modulo a prime power](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2216347/recursive-relation-of-multiplicative-orders-for-integers-modulo-a-prime-power) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%5En%5Cequiv%201%5Cpmod%7Bp%5Ek%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Amultiplicative%20order&p=1).

Comment: With $10^{n^{(k)}}\equiv 1\pmod{p^k}$, then $10^{n^{(k)}}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. Thus, $n \mid n^{(k)} \; \to \; n^{(k)} = mn$ for some integer $m$. By the [Lifting-the-exponent-lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting-the-exponent_lemma), using $x=10^n$ and $y=1$, we have $\nu_{p}(10^{n^{(k)}} - 1) = \nu_{p}(10^n-1)+\nu_{p}(m)$. Thus, for $j \ge \nu_{p}(10^n-1)$, we then have $n^{(j+1)}=pn^{(j)}$. With $p=3$, we have $j=1$. For other primes $p$ where $\nu_{p}(10^n-1)=1$, then your conjecture works as you stated since $j=0$ in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true in general. Exceptions modulo $p^2$ are called "base-10 [Wieferich primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime)", and there are [three known, namely 3, 487, and 56598313](https://oeis.org/A045616)—although there are conjectured to be infinitely many.